# Problem with Unit Testing Exercise, module not found

Tags: python, pytest

I am stuck on an exercise. These are the files I was given:

**A readme file:**

Before you begin, make sure to run this command in your terminal to install pytest:

```
pip install -U pytest
```

Then, to run pytest, just enter:

```
pytest
```

Right now, not all of the tests should pass. Fix the function to pass all its tests! Once all your tests pass, try writing some additional unit tests of your own!

**A "compute-launch.py" file:**

```
def days_until_launch(current_day, launch_day):
    """"Returns the days left before launch.
    
    current_day (int) - current day in integer
    launch_day (int) - launch day in integer
    """
    return launch_day - current_day
```

**A "test-compute-launch.py" file:**

```
from compute_launch import days_until_launch

def test_days_until_launch_4():
    assert(days_until_launch(22, 26) == 4)

def test_days_until_launch_0():
    assert(days_until_launch(253, 253) == 0)

def test_days_until_launch_0_negative():
    assert(days_until_launch(83, 64) == 0)
    
def test_days_until_launch_1():
    assert(days_until_launch(9, 10) == 1)
```

**This is my problem:**
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'compute_launch'

I have tried looking at other Stack Overflow threads which contain the same error "no module named" but I was not able to understand how this problem could be fixed. I have installed pytest. I need to be able to run the tests so I can see which tests are working and which are not. I don't need help with fixing or writing unit tests, I only need help with how to run the file to do the unit tests.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file name you used is invalid. As stated in [PEP 8](https://pep8.org/#package-and-module-names):

> ### Package and Module Names
>
> Modules should have short, all-lowercase names. Underscores can be used in the module name if it improves readability. Python packages should also have short, all-lowercase names, although the use of underscores is discouraged.

You have to rename the file and remove the dash. So change it from:

```
compute-launch.py
```

To:

```
compute_launch.py
```

Same with your test file `test-compute-launch.py`. The import should stay the same:

```
from compute_launch import days_until_launch
```

Answer (score 2):

You have saved the file as `compute-launch.py` but you are importing the function from `compute_launch`.
Notice that one has a hyphen while the other has an underscore.